# How to set SameSite attribute to 'None; Secure' in Rails5 and x-frame-options to all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-chrome

A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://example.com/ was set without the SameSite attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with SameSite=None and Secure. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Also, earlier I used to delete the X-Frame-Options in rails because of which iframe was working in chrome. Now after updating chrome to the latest version, it is throwing error Refused to display 'http://example.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

I used to delete it using code
 response.headers.delete("X-Frame-Options")

How to handle both these issues in latest version of chrome

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue here. But this solution worked for me: https://www.skcript.com/svr/samesite-issue-with-rails-in-chrome/

Gist:

```rb
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, {
  :key => '_application_session',
  :domain => :all,
  :same_site => :none,
  :secure => :true,
  :tld_length => 2
}
```